# Create shapefile in R using long and lat and export it

Tags: r, mapping, gis, shapefile, ggmap

I'm a R and GIS noob and would appreciate your help with my problem. I need to create a heatmap in R and have a dataset that has certain attribute and longitude and latitude columns for Washington DC metro area. I used ggmap to import a map for Washington DC and then added the plot of my dataset on top of that. The map looks great. Now I need to create a shapefile of this plot and export it in ArcGIS format. I looked around but I couldn't find tutorials or help pages on exactly what I want to do. Here's the code I used:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

myLocation <- "Washington DC"
#Getting a map of Washington DC metro area from google API
myMap <- get_map(location=myLocation, source="google", maptype="terrain", crop="FALSE")
ggmap(myMap) #maps the Washington DC map
zoom=5

#This plot the heatmap
ggmap(myMap) + 
  geom_density2d(data = mydata, 
                 aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), size = 0.3) + 
  stat_density2d(data = mydata, 
                 aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = ..level.., 
                     alpha = ..level..), size = 0.01, bins = 16, geom = "polygon") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") + 
  scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE)
```

This command works for me. I am now lost on how to create a shapefile based on the DC map and my plotted points and how to export it. I explored the library shapefiles but couldn't find what I was looking for.

This is what my dataset "mydata" looks like

```
ID_Var         latitude      longitude
223573820000001 38.8529910  -77.3640670
435153420000004 39.0964730  -76.5175040
579885949000002 38.9926000  -76.8358700
218543557000001 39.3958180  -76.4634520
578842012000004 38.9113450  -76.7900130
214727140000003 39.4023900  -76.4168250
214726688000001 39.4455920  -76.6112660
214760285000002 39.2898340  -76.6021910
214738051000001 39.2529070  -77.0197160
214727140000002 39.4023900  -76.4168250
```

Comment: where's `mydata`?. You'll need to build polygons (and more) and then write out a shapefile. `sp`, `rgdal` and other packages can help.

Comment: Others might know differently, but I'm not aware of any way you can take a Google Map (which is a png image) and convert it to a vector for a shapefile. You might have better luck downloading open data of Washington (from, for example, Open Street Map) and styling that, then adding your heatmap and exporting.

Comment: The google map won't be but you can take the data frame of polygons for the density and put that into a shapefile.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! So I had understood that the get_map function in ggmap helped me export a raster file from one of its sources (googlemap, open street map etc). I followed the tutorial here but modified it a little bit to create heatmap: https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/ggmap/ggmapCheatsheet.pdf